# Conditional context manager and decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, contextmanager

I have the following Python code littered throughout my code base which profiles a code block and sends the results to a monitoring solution if the `SHOULD_PROFILE` environment variable is set.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    if os.environ.get("SHOULD_PROFILE"):
        stack.enter_context(profile())
    ...
```

I would like to consolidate this snippet into a single context manager / decorator so it can be used as a context manager AND a decorator:

```
with profile_if_enabled():
    ...

# AND

@profile_if_enabled()
def func():
    ....
```

This is what I've come up with but it isn't working.

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator, ExitStack

class profile_if_enabled(ContextDecorator):
    def __enter__(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            if os.environ.get("SHOULD_PROFILE"):
                stack.enter_context(profile())
            return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        return False
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the indentation level of `return self` is one too many? Also, with `ContextDecorator` the decorator should be with parentheses, too: `@profile_if_enabled()`

Comment: @Arseny just added the parentheses but it didn't help. Updated the question above as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using the [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator:

```
import os
from contextlib import ExitStack, contextmanager

@contextmanager
def profile_if_enabled():
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        if os.environ.get("SHOULD_PROFILE"):
            stack.enter_context(profile())
        yield
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt fails because as soon as you `return self`, you leave the `with ExitStack() as stack:` block, and the ExitStack performs cleanup. You need to perform cleanup in `__exit__`, not when `__enter__` returns.

`ContextDecorator` requires a reusable, ideally reentrant context manager, which doesn't match your needs well. Even if you get something working, it will most likely break if you try to call a profiled function from another profiled function, or if you try to run two profiled functions in different threads at the same time.

It'd be cleaner to just write a decorator manually:

```
def profile_if_enabled(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if os.environ.get('SHOULD_PROFILE'):
            with profile():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If you really want something that works as both a decorator and a context manager, you can check for the presence of an argument:

```
def profile_if_enabled(func=None):
    if func is None:
        return profile()

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if os.environ.get('SHOULD_PROFILE'):
            with profile():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This would then be used as either `with profile_if_enabled():` or `@profile_if_enabled`. Note that unlike with `ContextDecorator`, the use as a decorator does not have parentheses.

If you don't need to support changing the `SHOULD_PROFILE` setting during execution, you could alternatively restructure the code to avoid repeating the check:

```
if os.environ.get('SHOULD_PROFILE'):
    def profile_if_enabled(func=None):
        if func is None:
            return profile()

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with profile():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
else:
    def profile_if_enabled(func=None):
        if func is None:
            return contextlib.nullcontext()
        return func
```

Comment: This can't be used as a context manager. Is there anyway to create something that can be used as both a context manager and a decorator?

Comment: @JohnnyMetz: Answer expanded.